# Regex to replace a period (.) when appearing alone or with spaces but not a number with a decimal point r

Tags: regex, r

Given input vector (iv)

```
iv <- c(.10,.15,"hello","."," . ",". ")
```

I'm using:

```
out <- sub(regexp,NA,iv)
```

I want output vector like this:

```
.10,.15,"hello",NA,NA,NA
```

but, don't know how to form the regexp to get what I need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1894891, I think you're looking for `negative lookahead`. If so, please check my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  gsub('^\\s*[.]\\s*$', 'NA',c(.10,.15,"hello","."," . ",". "))
  [1] "0.1"   "0.15"  "hello" "NA"    "NA"    "NA"
```

**EDIT** replace '`NA`' by `NA`

```
 gsub('^\\s*[.]\\s*$', NA,c(.10,.15,"hello","."," . ",". "))
[1] "0.1"   "0.15"  "hello" NA      NA      NA
```

**EDIT** using `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
x <- c(.10,.15,"hello","."," . ",". ")
x[str_trim(x) == '.'] <- NA
x
[1] "0.1"   "0.15"  "hello" NA      NA      NA
```

Comment: if you use NA as a replacement in `gsub` then you're getting the characters "N" "A".   ie: `is.na("NA") == FALSE.    You'd have to pass your regex through to `[`

Comment: This worked really well for me, thanks so much! In addition, I now know how to use the regex in grep and related functions. And...it helps lower my intimidation to learn more about reg expressions which seem very powerful and useful but avoided until now.

Comment: If we pass NA instead of 'NA', it appears to work as verified with appropriate TRUE when tested with is.na(out)

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is `negative lookahead` in regular expressions. You want to check for `.` not followed by a `number (0-9)` and replace them with `NA`. If this logic is what you want, then it can be implemented in 1 line as follows:

```
gsub("\\.(?![0-9])", NA, iv, perl=T)
# [1] "0.1"   "0.15"  "hello" NA      NA      NA
```

Logic: search for a dot that is not followed by a number and replace them with `NA`.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to replace the values with `NA` then you will want to use some form of the assignment operators.

A simple approach:

```
 iv[gsub(" ", "", iv)=="."] <- NA
```

quick explanation:

If the strings to replace were all the same (ie, `"."`), then you could simply call
`iv[ iv=="."] <- NA`.

However, in order to catch all the extra spaces, you can either search for the myriad "." combinations making sure to exclude the `.10`, `.15` etc, or instead
you can remove all the spaces and then you have the simpler situation where you can use `==`.

Incidentally, if you want to search for a period in regex in R, you need to escape the period for regex `\.` and then you need to escape the escape for `R`, `\\.`

---

Edit:  Note that the line above does not permanently remove the spaces from `iv`.  Take a look at `gsub(" ", "", iv)=="."`  This returns a vector of T/F, which in turn is being used to filter `iv`. Other than the `NA` values, `iv` remains unchanged.

**EDIT #2:**
If you want the changes to be saved to a different vector, you can use the following:

```
 out <- iv
 out[gsub(" ", "", iv)=="."] <- NA
```

Comment: Thank you Ricardo. This is so helpful for my learning. In my particular case, the data is kind of a mess, so I cannot count on spaces being removable, for example, "hello dolly" we'd want to keep the spaces.

Comment: @user1895891 don't worry, the spaces are not being removed permanently. please see edit

Comment: That's why this is such a neat solution - it's a logical test for what the value would be if you took away the spaces. If that would match "." then it is given NA

Comment: This solution results in a vector of NA for me...unsure what I'm doing wrong. Discussed in suggested Edit #2

Answer (score -1):

The reqular expression:

```
       "^ *\. *$"
```

Comment: Thank you! I've spent the last 20 minutes trying to get it to work in a sub expression. sub("regex",NA,iv)...sub("(regex)",NA,iv)...sub("[regex]",NA,iv)...sub("([regex])",NA,iv... I assumed just having the regex, it would be obvious how to use it. Help?

Comment: @agstudy, I think this is downvoted because it doesn't work in `R` ;)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta this works for me in R `gsub('^ *\\. *$', 'NA',c(.10,.15,"hello","."," . ",". "))`. This is a good answer. The idea is here.

Comment: @agstudy, try the following:   `any(is.na(gsub('^ *\\. *$', 'NA',c(.10,.15,"hello","."," . ",". "))))`